# Fire validation rule if the selected date is not within 30 days

Tags: validation-rule

I'm trying to write validation rule which states that,

`schedule_date__c` should be within 30 days from `start_date__c` and `end_date__c`

I have done the following but not sure why the validation is not working.

Validation rule:

```
AND(schedule_date__c,
((start_date__c - end_date__c) < 30))
```

Comment: you mention `schedule_date__c`  as a key part of the requirement, but your VR has no reference to it - based on what you've shared, you're looking at the difference between start and end date only. It'd be helpful to [edit] your question to provide your full VR as written in your org vs. the way you laid it out as I'm not clear on whether you're using `OR()` and whether you actually have more to what you've attempted than what you've shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AND` logical function is [described](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.usefulFormulaFields.meta/usefulFormulaFields/customize_functions.htm) as this:

> Returns a TRUE response if all values are true; returns a FALSE response if one or more values are false.

So in your Validation Rule, you checking for this:

1. Is there a value in the `schedule_date__c` field?

**AND**

2. Is the difference between the `start_date_c` and `end_date__c` values less than 30 [days]?

---

There are a couple of issues:

1. You are not directly comparing `schedule_date__c` to anything to do with Start or End Dates.
2. Subtracting End Date from Start Date (assuming that End Date is always later than Start Date) will *always* be less than 30, because the answer will always be negative.

---

If by

> `schedule_date__c` should be within 30 days from `start_date__c` and `end_date__c`

you mean that Schedule Date should be inside of 30 days after the Start Date or inside of 30 days before the End Date, then the following Validation Rule formula should work*:

```
OR(
   (schedule_date__c - start_date__c) > 30,
   (end_date__c - schedule_date__c) > 30
)
```

** assuming that all the fields are the same Date type*

---

### UPDATE

After chat discussion, requirements were clarified and some "givens" determined.

**GIVENS**

- End Date will always be after/greater than Start Date (separate validation)
- A Schedule Date value is not allowed if there is no Start Date and End Date (separate validation)

**REQUIREMENTS**

- Schedule Date must be after/greater than the End Date
- Schedule Date must be within 30 days of the Start Date

#### VALIDATION RULE

```
AND(
  NOT(ISBLANK(schedule_date__c)),
  OR(
    schedule_date__c <= end_date__c,
    (schedule_date__c - start_date__c) > 30
  )
)
```

What this does:

- If Schedule Date has a value [user selected something]...
  AND
- Schedule Date is on or before the End Date -OR- Schedule Date is greater than 30 days after Start Date...

...then the formula returns `TRUE` and the error is displayed:

[image]

Comment: so I have three dates, start_date, end_date and schedule_date (same data type), the two dates (start/end) assume those dates are selected by the user, the schedule_date__c should be within 30 days from either start_date__c  or end_date__c dates, whichever is the latest.

Comment: So the Start Date can be a later date than the End Date?

Comment: Those start and end date validation I have take care.

Comment: So you are saying that you figured this out? In other words, you don't need an answer anymore?

Comment: No I’m not, I replied to your last comment

Comment: I apologize, but I am not following how that answered my comment. In your first comment you stated, "30 days from either start_date__c or end_date__c dates, whichever is the latest." From that I inferred that Start can be later than End, and I asked for clarification.  I asked because it matters whether Start can be later than End - that would add extra logic to the Validation Rule formula.

Comment: Sorry for confusing you. Start date cannot be later than end date

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129099/discussion-between-moonpie-and-nick-kahn).